# How to select date and time less than a timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am making a join, and have to select rows where date and time is less than a particular date and time. I have a date and time column (combined) in my table, called 'hour'.

I'm trying to convert string to timestamp in the where clause (by using to_timestamp). The where clause if changed to a select query, stands perfectly in itself. But when used in my code (join), causes a syntax error.

```
Select 
t1.revenue,
t2.impressions

from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id

where t2.hour < to_timestamp('2019-07-24 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

I get a syntax error near my 'where' clause.

Comment: Postgres? Or MySQL?

Comment: missing comma after t1.revenue ?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry No need to downvote.  This is a Postgres question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There's every need.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is probably being caused by a missing comma in the `SELECT` clause.  But beyond that, your query has other issues.  Consider this updated version:

```
select 
    t1.revenue,
    t2.impressions
from t1
left join t2
    on t1.id = t2.id and
       t2.hour < '2019-07-24 23:59:59'::timestamp;
```

Given that your are doing a left join from `t1` to `t2`, the restriction on `t2` which currently appears in your `WHERE` clause most likely should be moved to the `ON` clause of the join.  Not doing this would possibly mean filtering off records from `t1` which would defeat the purpose of the left join.

Also note that you can just use `::timestamp` to convert a string literal to a timestamp, though you may not even need to do this.

Comment: Hello! I've edited the comma, I just made that mistake writing down my question.

Comment: I don't quite understand the part about filtering off records from t1 part. I think in a left join, no records from t1 will be filtered. The where condition only shortlists the entries from t2 that will be joined.

Comment: Not true at all.  Your current `WHERE` clause could absolutely remove any `t1` record which does not match to an hour.

Comment: There is no "hour" column in t1. That's why I'm confused as to how filtering hour in t2 will remove entries from t1

Comment: Imagine that every record in `t1` will only match to at most 1 record in `t2`.  Then the join happens, and afterwards the `WHERE` clause is applied.  If you put the restriction on `t2.hour` in the `WHERE` clause, then any record in `t1` which fails the hour requirement will be _removed_.  This could happen for a non matching join _or_ a matching join which however has the wrong `t2.hour` value.  My version guarantees that every `t1` record appears in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, you are missing a comma ',' in the `SELECT` clause.